# How to animate a React component as it is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple Notifications component which renders an array of Notification components. I would like to have the notifications fade in and out. So I installed `react-transition-group` and gave it a try.

I can't quite get it to work, though. When a new notification is added, it does fade in, but when a notification is removed, it simply disappears - it does not fade out.

Here's what I have:

Component:

```
export default function Notifications({ notifications }) {
  return (
    <NotificationsContainer style={{ top: 'calc(100% - ' + (4.5 * notifications.length) + 'em)'}}>
      <TransitionGroup className="notifications">
        {[...notifications].reverse().map(notification => (
          <CSSTransition key={notification.timestamp} timeout={500} classNames="notification">
            <Notification emoji={notification.emoji} />
          </CSSTransition>
        ))}
      </TransitionGroup>
    </NotificationsContainer>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```css
  .notification-enter {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .notification-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .notification-exit {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .notification-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  }
```